# Kohana - Need advice about routing

Tags: kohana

```
application
modules
   myModule
      classes
         controller
         model
         helper
         foo.php
      views
      init.php
```

This is the file structure of my module. I need to create route inside of init.php, that will allow me to call foo.php file from anywhere in the project. The class in foo.php does not extend any kohana classes - that's the place stopping me.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Routing applies to controllers, not random classes. As long as you register the module, the class will be autoloaded whenever you do `new Foo;`. They don't need to extend kohana classes to be autoloaded.

Comment: I need this for ajax. Calling backend file using jquery resolves to "class not found" when I wanna use there anything kohana-related. The only way is routing.

Comment: Then you'll need to make a controller with a route to access the class. Ajax is not any more special than a normal URI call with a browser.

Comment: You need a controller that maps to a URI via a route. That controller can then call the `Foo` class. You could also put the logic into a controller directly, but I can't say if that's correct or not without seeing the code.

Comment: I just hoped there's another way, I don't really wanna create controller folder for one class, it kind of makes the whole module's folder structure less readable - anyway, thanks!

Comment: That's what ajax is. It's simply a URI call, so you'll need a controller class/action to handle the call. Your browser can't reach right into your php files with magic or anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with: `include Kohana::find_file('classes', 'foo');` and don't forget to enable your module in `bootstrap.php: 'myModule'    => MODPATH.'myModule'`.